# How to fetch data from custom tables in Oracle webcenter content server.(Auxiliary Metadata) Document level?

Tags: oracle, metadata, oracle12c, webcenter, oracle-ucm

I have been working on Oracle web center content 12c for a while and I am using meta data on document level (auxiliary meta data set). Since these meta data are not a part of doc Meta table, they cannot be fetched using any of the search services. These meta data create a custom table in the content server which I am not able to access. Has anyone worked on Auxiliary metadata set? And how do I fetch data from a custom table?

Comment: Cross posted here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3949648

Answer (score 0):

There might be an out of the box service you can use. If you search the *RecordsManagement* component directory, you might find one.

Otherwise, you may need to code your own by [creating a custom component](https://jonathanhult.com/blog/2015/08/custom-webcenter-content-components-links/), creating a service and creating a [ServiceHandler](http://www.redstonecontentsolutions.com/technical-blog/ucm-service-handlers-and-javafilters) that queries the database and brings back your data.